# DataGridView is not Showing All Records in a Table VB.NET SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I have a table SalariesSettingsForEmployee in which the employee Allowances and Deductions are saved.

All Types of Allowances and Deductions are loaded into GridView columns and employees in Gridview Rows. (with their respective values)

Problem is the data is loaded into Grid View only of one (or first) employee and not all.

I made two subroutines.
Here is my code.

Kindly advise if I am doing something wrong here.

Thanks and Regards,

```
Sub CreateEmployeeRows()

    Dim subtotal As Double = 0
    Dim NetTotal As Double = 0
    Dim tempval As Double = 0
    Dim rno As Integer = 0
    Dim BasicSalary As Double = 0
    Dim DeductionTotal As Double = 0
    Dim GrandTotal As Double = 0

    BasicSalary = SQLGetNumericFieldValue("Select Amount From SalariesSettingsForEmployee Where AllowanceName='BASIC SALARY'", "Amount")
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
    Dim sqlcmmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Try
        sqlcmmd.Connection = DAL.OpenSqlConnection
        sqlcmmd.CommandText = "Select * From SalariesSettingsForEmployee Where AllowanceType='Allowance'"
        Dim sreader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader

        sreader = sqlcmmd.ExecuteReader
        While sreader.Read

            subtotal = BasicSalary

            dr(0) = sreader("EmployeeCode").ToString
            dr(1) = sreader("EmployeeName").ToString
            dr(2) = sreader("BranchCode")
            dr(3) = sreader("BranchName")

            If sreader("AmountType").ToString = "Fixed Amount" Then
                tempval = sreader("Amount")
                subtotal = subtotal + tempval
            ElseIf sreader("AmountType").ToString = "Percentage" Then
                tempval = subtotal * CDbl(sreader("Amount")) / 100
                subtotal = subtotal + tempval
            End If
            dr(sreader("AllowanceName")) = tempval
            ''sreader("Amount")
            GrandTotal = subtotal
            dr(GrossTotalColName) = GrandTotal
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            txtRunPayrollGird.DataSource = dt

        End While
        sreader.Close()
        sreader = Nothing
        DAL.CloseSQLConnection()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    'End of Allowance Totals

    'Calculate Deduction Totals
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Try
        cmd.Connection = DAL.OpenSqlConnection
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From SalariesSettingsForEmployee Where AllowanceType='Deduction'"

        Dim rdr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While rdr.Read
            tempval = 0

            If rdr("AmountType").ToString = "Fixed Amount" Then
                tempval = rdr("Amount")
                subtotal = subtotal + tempval
                DeductionTotal = DeductionTotal + tempval
            ElseIf rdr("AmountType").ToString = "Percentage" Then
                tempval = GrandTotal * CDbl(rdr("Amount")) / 100
                subtotal = subtotal + tempval
            End If
            dr(rdr("AllowanceName")) = tempval
            ''sreader("Amount")

            dr(NetSalaryColName) = GrandTotal - DeductionTotal
            NetTotal = NetTotal + (GrandTotal - DeductionTotal)
            txtNetPayable.Text = NetTotal
            dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            txtRunPayrollGird.DataSource = dt
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Sub CreateColumns()
    Dim Sqlcmmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim Sreader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    Try

        dt = New DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Employee ID")
        dt.Columns.Add("Employee Name")
        dt.Columns.Add("Branch Code")
        dt.Columns.Add("Branch Name")

        'For Additions

        Sqlcmmd.Connection = DAL.OpenSqlConnection
        Sqlcmmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SalariesPaySettings WHERE AllowanceType='Allowance'"
        Sqlcmmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Sreader = Sqlcmmd.ExecuteReader

        While Sreader.Read

            dt.Columns.Add(Sreader("AllowanceName").ToString.Trim)

        End While
        dt.Columns.Add(GrossTotalColName)
        Sreader.Close()
        Sreader = Nothing
        DAL.CloseSQLConnection()
        Sqlcmmd.Connection = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    'For Deductions
    Try
        Dim Sqlcmmd1 As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Sqlcmmd1.Connection = DAL.OpenSqlConnection
        Sqlcmmd1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM SalariesPaySettings WHERE AllowanceType='Deduction'"
        Sqlcmmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim Sreader1 As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        Sreader1 = Sqlcmmd1.ExecuteReader
        While Sreader1.Read
            dt.Columns.Add(Sreader1("AllowanceName").ToString.Trim)
        End While
        dt.Columns.Add(NetSalaryColName)
        txtRunPayrollGird.DataSource = dt
        Sreader1.Close()
        Sreader1 = Nothing
        DAL.CloseSQLConnection()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edP0G.jpg)

'

''''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your are creating a single `DataRow` on this line:

```
Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
```

and reusing that row in the loops, overwriting values written to the row in previous iterations. What you need to do, is to create a new `DataRow` for each iteration of the loops.

In your first loop:

```
While sreader.Read

    ' Create new row.
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow

    subtotal = BasicSalary
```

Similarly for the second loop:

```
While rdr.Read
    tempval = 0

        ' Create new row.
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow

        If rdr("AmountType").ToString = "Fixed Amount" Then
```

Comment: Hi Robert, Thankyou for your reply. I tried what you said and now succeeded to show all data. But the problem is Its showing Payheads (like Basic Salary, Transport allowance etc) in multiple rows. For ex First row is basic salary and it creates a new row of Transport Allowance and calculates the gross total in the second row (Transport Allowance). Can you please suggest me a way to show all allowances of an employee in a single row? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @Dearest - You would have to create a new row only when needed (that is, one row for each employee), add to it all the column values you want, and then add it to the table. I see that you have two loops. You may have to combine them into a single loop iterating through your two datareaders to achieve this. Another solution would be to change your SQL to retrieve all the information you need for employees with a single datareader. Either way, a more detailed description of your data would be needed to provide help. I suggest that you try to solve it, and post another question if required.

Comment: Thanks for reply Robert. I will try all the ways you suggested and let you know.

Comment: @Dearest - Good! In the meantime you can accept this answer. Thanks!